# Обособление "или вроде того"

Tags: разговорная-речь

Подскажите, будьте добры, нужна ли запятая: "Он придумал программу для ТВ(,) или вроде того". В диалоге.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) ***Он придумал программу для ТВ или вроде того.*** Союз ИЛИ разделительный.

(2) ***Он придумал программу для ТВ, или вроде того.*** Союз ИЛИ присоединительный.

Чаще используется первый вариант без обособления, паузы нет. Но второй вариант тоже возможен, если оборот имеет характер добавочного сообщения.

Примеры

Мы играли в каких-то космонавтов, пришельцев **или вроде того.** [Владимир Спектр. Face Control (2002)]

Недели через две **или вроде того** я с ними одну диверсию не совсем аккуратно сработал. [Вадим Кожевников. Щит и меч. Книга вторая (1968)]

...он легко приучил ее слышать в ответ на вопрос о любви тарабарское утверждение: кундырым тараду, **или вроде того**... [Сергей Носов. Грачи улетели (2005)]